# Does anything happen if I give a severed head item to a character with the same name?

Tags: darkest-dungeon

I have found an item called Dismas' Head and I have had a highwayman character called Dismas at one point, but I dismissed him. What would have happened if he equipped his own(?) head? Does it have any effects? Or does a head with one of your current characters' names never drop?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I still have my Dismas in this game (though I am contemplating firing him because as you can see he's in a bit of a state).  He has never reacted in any way to my equipping the trinket on him.  His damage went up, his health went down, and he's more vulnerable to stress damage.

[image]